# start/stop a Google Cloud VM from desktop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gsutil

I have a VM running on Google cloud that I would like to start and stop.

I am able to start/stop it from another VM in the same project using the command

```
sudo gcloud compute instances stop my-daily-data-vm --zone us-central1-c
```

Now, I would like to start/stop it from my Windows desktop. (FYI I do have gsutil installed on it). Is there a way I can do this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same `gcloud` CLI is available for Windows in your Command Prompt or Powershell. [Here's the quickstart from Google.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows)

The command to start/stop your VM is the exact same on all platforms.

p.s. don't use `sudo` for the `gcloud` command.

Comment: If you cannot install `gcloud` on your machine, you can always use plink to executy command on ssh hosts remotely.